# Does water self ionize to protons or hydronium ions, or both?

Tags: water

The most common equation for the self ionization of water I've seen is with protons and hydroxyl ions as products.

H<sub>2</sub>O ⇌ H<sup>+</sup> + OH<sup>-</sup>

I've also seen the following equation with hydronium ions as a product instead of protons

2H<sub>2</sub>O ⇌ H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup> + OH<sup>-</sup>

Does the first equation actually happen, or is it just an abbreviation for the second? Or do both species (hydronium and protons) exist in solution, or something more complicated?

Comment: Bare protons do not exist in chemistry. First form is a shorthand for the second.

Comment: Ivan is right but technically even the second equation is a short hand for how acidic protons are held by a whole network of H2O.